# Is SQS short polling ever preferable to long polling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, polling, long-polling

Amazon SQS supports two modes of polling for available messages: short polling and long polling. With long polling, the consumer specifies a timeout of 1-20 seconds to wait for available messages.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html):

> By default, Amazon SQS uses *short polling*, querying only a subset of its servers (based on a weighted random distribution), to determine whether any messages are available for a response.

> Long polling offers the following benefits:
>
> - Eliminate empty responses by allowing Amazon SQS to wait until a message is available in a queue before sending a response. Unless the connection times out, the response to the `ReceiveMessage` request contains at least one of the available messages, up to the maximum number of messages specified in the `ReceiveMessage` action.
> - Eliminate false empty responses by querying all—rather than a subset of—Amazon SQS servers.
> - Return messages as soon as they become available.

The above characteristics make long polling seem pretty good. So is there a use case where short polling is preferable?

In particular, for high-throughput queues, is short polling faster than long polling?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Long polling is almost always preferable to short polling. Following are two use cases where short polling might be desirable(given in SQS FAQs):

- When immediate message processing is required.
- When you poll multiple queues in a single thread.

From SQS [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/):

> **In almost all cases, Amazon SQS long polling is preferable to short
>   polling.** Long-polling requests let your queue consumers receive
>   messages as soon as they arrive in your queue while reducing the
>   number of empty ReceiveMessageResponse instances returned.
>
> Amazon SQS long polling results in higher performance at reduced cost
>   in the majority of use cases. However, **if your application expects an
>   immediate response from a ReceiveMessage call, you might not be able
>   to take advantage of long polling without some modifications to your
>   application.**
>
> For example, **if your application uses a single thread to poll multiple
>   queues, switching from short polling to long polling will probably not
>   work, because the single thread will wait for the long-poll timeout on
>   any empty queues, delaying the processing of any queues that might
>   contain messages.**
>
> In such an application, it is a good practice to use a single thread
>   to process only one queue, allowing the application to take advantage
>   of the benefits that Amazon SQS long polling provides.

Comment: "When immediate message processing is required," isn't quite correct. It should be something like, "when the call to ReceiveMessage must return immediately". Long-polling actually allows for more immediate processing of messages than short polling. Note the "return messages as soon as they become available" in the questions quoted AWS docs.

Comment: What exactly is the cost differential between short and long?

Comment: @JatinMorar mainly cost of empty receives, exact number will be depending on the actual use case.